# How to get latest data inserted in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have this kind of table:

```
ID        NUMBER     DATE_INPUT
 A             1     2019-05-26
 A             2     2019-05-27
 A             0     2019-05-28
 B             0     2019-05-27
 B             1     2019-05-28
```

I use `GROUP BY` to get group the data and the result is:

```
 ID        NUMBER     DATE_INPUT     
 A             1     2019-05-26
 B             0     2019-05-27
```

The desired output is:

```
 ID        NUMBER     DATE_INPUT     
 A             0     2019-05-28
 B             1     2019-05-28
```

Comment: First, get a PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 0):

you can use a correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename a
where date_input = (select max(date_input) from tablename b
where a.id=b.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

use order by `desc`

```
select * from tablename group by ID order by date_input desc
```

> With order by all new date will desc so new one will appear first

Answer (score 0):

Give this code a try.

`select l.* 
from table l
inner join (
  select 
    date_input as latest 
  from table 
  group by id order by date_input desc
) r
  on l.date_input= r.latest and l.id= r.id
order by date_input desc`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the DATE_INPUT field, you can use GROUP and ORDER to get what you want:

`SELECT ID, NUMBER, DATE_INPUT
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY DATE_INPUT DESC`